# ASP.Net MVC application seemingly ignoring database connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My application is seemingly ignoring the database connection string when connecting to the MS SQL database server we have, and I'm not experienced in ASP.Net or IIS, so I'm not sure what or where the error is.

For background, I had a working ASP.Net MVC application on .Net 4.5, unfortunately I need to deploy it on an old server that only runs .Net 4. I've therefore had to roll it back to .Net 4, which took a while and involved me replacing NuGet packages and removing any parts that reported compatibility errors.

When I run the app locally from VS Community 2015, it works fine, connecting to the database, loading what is needed. When I publish it to our test server (using IIS 7 and running a .Net 4 application pool) it gives the following error:

Login failed for user ''

with an exception:

```
[InvalidOperationException: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.]
```

I Googled the exception and tried a solution of adding:

```
Database.SetInitializer<FormsContext>(null);
```

to the application_start method. That then gave caused this exception (same error with the user ''):

```
[EntityException: the underlying provider failed to open]
```

I'm not sure if that's better or worse. My connection strings (with the password and server blanked out) are:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=forms;Integrated Security=False;Trusted_Connection=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=formsReadWrite;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="FormsContext1" connectionString="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=forms;Integrated Security=False;Trusted_Connection=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=formsReadWrite;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm a bit out of my depth now, as it worked before, and seems to work on my local machine. I've Googled everywhere, but most answers involve using integrated security, which I'm definitely not doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for the connection to the database is (the start of the db context, it's fairly large after this, and just creates each field):

```
public partial class FormsContext : DbContext
{
    public FormsContext()
        : base("name=FormsContext1")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<form> forms { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<input> inputs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<option> options { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<section> sections { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<user> users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<reveal> reveals { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<survey> surveys { get; set; }
```

Code for the connection:

```
using (var data = new FormsContext())
        {

            //Query the database for the form details
            var detailsQuery = (from d in data.forms 
                                where d.name == name
                                select d);

            var details = new forms.form();
```

It connects a few times, but uses the same logic as the above.

Comment: On your test server, have you granted access to sql server for user `formsReadWrite`?

Comment: Yes, it's the same connection string used for the .net 4.5 application, and when I publish that to the same site, on the same server, using the same application pool, it works fine. So that user can definitely access the SQL server.

Comment: Can you post the code where you provide the connectionstring to entity framework? And can you make sure the web.config on your test server has the same content like that one in your debug environment? So we can eleminate as much possibilities.

Comment: I've checked the development server and the web.config is definitely the same. The code is now in the question, it creates a dbcontext (I've not put all of that in, as it's fairly large), and the connection uses that.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but have you tried changing `base("name=FormsContext1")` to `base("FormsContext1")`?

Comment: @JamieDunstan No, thats correct. `name=` tells EF that the connectionstring is in the web.config. Edit: Source: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: you don't trust your own connection?

Comment: you don't trust your own connection? You seem to have allot in you Connection string to be honest, all you need is data source, initial catalog, id and password. For entity connection provider is not sqlclient should be providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

Comment: @Mark Homer I'll admit I added a few bits and pieces in an attempt to solve the issue 'Trusted Connection = False' being once of them, but mostly everything else was built automatically via Visual Studio. I tried changing the provide name and I got an error keyword does not exist for 'data source', so I think SQL as a provider is fine, after all, it does work in .Net 4.5.

Comment: @ James every connection I ever made to EF the providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" SQL Client is for Database connection are you saying Visual Studio made EF conn with SQL client? I have never seen it tbh

Comment: @JamesR I tried to reproduce your problem in one of our oldest test systems (WinServer 2008, SQL Server 2008), but I was unable to get any results. 
@MarkHomer I'm using EF since version 6.0.0, and the providerName I used was `System.Data.SqlClient` every time. Maybe it was different in older versions of EF.

Comment: @Patrick I am using EF since 2 and using 6.1 now and still the client is EntityClient for the EF connection and surely always will be does the name tell you SQLclient for EF conn hmmmm, the SQLclient is for the Database. Error: [EntityException: the underlying provider failed to open]

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this, but i'm trying to get this to work on a Windows 2003 server, which is why I can't even think about upgrading to .Net 4.5 unfortunately. The application works fine on our Windows 2008 development server. I've managed to fix it (kind of), and posted an answer as such.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this, although it's not really a solution as such. I think it may have been to do with the rolling back of the application to .Net 4, rather than anything else, as it worked on a later server, and I had to muddle through.

As a result I started again, with a new MVC project, and seeing as Visual Studio no longer supports anything prior to MVC5 and .Net 4.5.1, I had to roll it back again, but doing it in an empty project was a lot easier. I also cleaned up the project a bit when copying it over, so that may have helped.

I managed to get it working late on Friday, at least to the point that it loads without throwing an error. Hopefully we'll be able to get the server updated at some point to at least Windows Server 2008, and will be able to run .Net 4.5.1.